# Can I create and publish an iPhone app by building it in a second hand Mac?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore, mac

I have never published an app to app store. 
I have a chance to buy an apple mac from someone.

Is it possible to use that to publish to app store? What if the first owner was also a developer?

If I buy Mac with the only intention of publishing an app should I only go for a new one to get developer license or I can do it in a second hand Mac also?

Comment: You will need a reasonably new mac. One that supports current software. As apple brings out newer updates developers have to stay up to date with their OS. Take this into consideration, there is no point getting a second hand mac if in a years time it is no longer capable of running the necessary software. It doesn't matter whether the previous owner was a developer, however if he or she is and they are selling their mac, it might imply that it is no longer suitable.

Answer (score 2):

So long as the computer is an ["Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later"](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html), it doesn't matter.  **In theory.**

However, iOS 5.1 and up require a version of XCode which will only run on Lion.  So you need a computer that's [capable of running Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4949) in order to do any serious development.

Answer (score 2):

The most current and best supported versions of Xcode for developing iPhone apps often requires a Mac that runs the latest released version of OS X, currently Mountain Lion 10.8.4.  Make sure the Mac meets the system requirements if this OS is not installed already.

You can delete the previous users keys and certificates from a used Mac.  After paying Apple $99/annum to enroll in the iOS Developers program, you can install your own certificates and provisions, perhaps in a brand new clean User account.